# OpenCL, cannot repeat the same kernel sequence within the program thrice

Tags: opencl

I'm creating a program that simulates a model using OpenCL or C++ so you can compare the simulation time after. The OpenCL fractions the work so you simulate a part at a time, the same kernel is enqueued several times so it covers the entire simulation (I do this in order to retrieve the data and overlap compute time and data transfer time)

This program works perfectly, but it has a problem: once the simulation you choose is complete, it returns to the main menu so you can simulate more times. You can do as many C++ simulations as you want, but EVERYTIME on the third OpenCL simulation the program freezes, it doesn't show an error or anything, it just freezes just after I wait for every queue to finish (by setting CL_TRUE in the last ReadBuffer)

I monitored the GPU utilization with VisualStudio and got the following results, each peak is a simulation, but they don't make sense for me since each simulation should use the same % of GPU I think. I guess it freezes because at the third it goes over 100%

[image: GPU utilization]

I don't understand why this happens. I release everything, queues, buffers, program, kernel and context, and I free the host pointer where I allocate the data after the simulation. This problem is not critical, but it is very bothersome since I would like to run several OpenCL simulations without having to restart the program. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to change the program so that all of the opencl structures are initialized in the beginning and reused and only released once the program exits? Because only reason I can think why it would happen on third iteration everytime assuming the parameters are always the same is that something is not actually released.

Comment: Also do you check error codes for all opencl calls?

Comment: Thank you very much! this solved the problem, Now the OpenCL simulation runs as many times as I want. I guess it is troublesome to initialize and release OpenCL variables for each simulation. I had the  error check only for enqueuing kernels, but I'll add  it for every command I enqueue.